# How can i push data into react-admin store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-admin

I'm trying to build a web app with react-admin and need to push data to the redux store. I read the React-admin docs (https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Actions.html) and when I try to do that, I get Failures.[image]

Here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withStyles, MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import {
    Menu,
    Notification,
    Sidebar,
        setSidebarVisibility, 
} from 'react-admin';

import {kidsLoad} from './customActions/KidsActions'

import AppBar from './MyAppBar';
const styles = theme => ({
    root: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        zIndex: 1,
        minHeight: '100vh',
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
        position: 'relative',
    },
    appFrame: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        overflowX: 'auto',
    },
    contentWithSidebar: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexGrow: 1,
    },
    content: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        flexGrow: 2,
        padding: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
        marginTop: '1em',
        paddingLeft: 5,
    },
});

class MyLayout extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.setSidebarVisibility(true);
        }

        componentDidMount(){
            const { kidsLoad, record } = this.props;

            kidsLoad({data: "HELLOOOOOOOOOOOO!!!!!"})

        }

    render() {
        const {
            children,
            classes,
            dashboard,
            isLoading,
            logout,
            open,
            title,
        } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className={classes.root}>
                <div className={classes.appFrame}>
                    <AppBar title={title} open={open} logout={logout} />
                    <main className={classes.contentWithSidebar}>

                        <div className={classes.content}>
                            {children}
                        </div>
                    </main>
                    <Notification />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

MyLayout.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.node]),
    dashboard: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        PropTypes.func,
        PropTypes.string,
    ]),
    isLoading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    // logout: componentPropType,
    setSidebarVisibility: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        kidsLoad: PropTypes.func,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ isLoading: state.admin.loading > 0 });
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { setSidebarVisibility, kidsLoad })(withStyles(styles)(MyLayout));
```

I did everything like in the documentation (https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Actions.html).

What did I do wrong?
How do you add data to the store in this framework?

Comment: can you paste the KidsLoad action ? Also, the Network tab should show an Ajax request, where you can get more information about the failure.

Answer (score 4):

This is going to be a quick answer that I leave for further improvement.

If I understand your question correctly you got some of your resources (entities) updated and you want react-admin to know about it and update its store accordingly triggering updates in app views if necessary.

The first thing we have to get is the `dispatch` function of the react-admin store. In my case, the source of resource update was a React component, so I used [`withDataProvider` decorator](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Actions.html#using-the-withdataprovider-decorator) to receive a reference to the `dispatch` function.

Once you have the `dispatch` function you dispatch, for example, `CRUD_UPDATE_SUCCESS` action for a particular resource update in the react-admin store.

```
import { CRUD_UPDATE_SUCCESS, FETCH_END, UPDATE } from 'react-admin';

dispatch({
  type: CRUD_UPDATE_SUCCESS,
  payload: { data },
  meta: {
    resource,
    notification: {
      body: 'ra.notification.dataSaved',
      level: 'info'
    },
    fetchResponse: UPDATE,
    fetchStatus: FETCH_END
  }
});
```

You can also use action creators from react-admin. Like `showNotification`, for example.

```
import { showNotification } from 'react-admin';

dispatch(showNotification(errorMessage, 'warning', { autoHideDuration: 10000 }));
```

A bit more consistent piece of code here to show how all this can work together. The `Updater` component here renders its child components passing them a resource `record` and subscribes for their `onSubmit` callback to perform entity saving and updating react-admin store.

```
import React from 'react';
import { 
  CRUD_UPDATE_SUCCESS, FETCH_END, UPDATE, withDataProvider, showNotification 
} from 'react-admin';

class Updater extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleUpdate(record) {
    const { resource, dataProvider, dispatch } = this.props;

    const payload = {
      id: record.id,
    };

    payload.data = {...record};

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      dataProvider(UPDATE, resource, payload)
        .then(({data}) => {
          dispatch({
            type: CRUD_UPDATE_SUCCESS,
            payload: { data },
            meta: {
              resource,
              notification: {
                body: 'ra.notification.dataSaved',
                level: 'info'
              },
              fetchResponse: UPDATE,
              fetchStatus: FETCH_END
            }
          });

          resolve(data);
        })
        .catch(e => {
          const errorMessage = e.message || e;

          this.setState({ errorMessage });

          dispatch(
            showNotification(errorMessage, 'warning', { autoHideDuration: 10000 })
          );

          reject(errorMessage);
        });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { record, children } = this.props;
    const { errorMessage } = this.state;

    return React.Children.only(React.cloneElement(children, {
      record,
      errorMessage,
      onUpdate: this.handleUpdate
    }));
  }
}

export default withDataProvider(Updater);
```

HTH, 
Ed